# Menu.playerSelection() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python

I don't know why it does that.

```py
self.slider = CTkSlider(self.startMenu_frame, from_=1, to=4, variable = playersNumber, number_of_steps= 4, command= self.playerSelection)
```

that is the line that is causing the probleme
thanks

I tried with `lambda`, `lambda x`... before `self.playerSelection`

Comment: Please see [ask] and provide enough information (in other words, make a [mre]) so that we can reproduce your problem ourselves.

Comment: `command=lambda _: self.playerSelection()`